# Error while adding a Calculated column to a list using Client Object Model

Tags: development, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, xml

I am trying to add some fields to list using the client object model. Everything is working except the Calculated field.

Every time SharePoint gives the error: An error occurred while parsing EntityName

```
fields.AddFieldAsXml(
"<Field Type='Calculated' DisplayName='Periode' LCID='1043' Name='Periode' ResultType='Text' ReadOnly='TRUE'><Formula>=RECHTS(\"00\"&MAAND([Rapportage periode]);2)&\"-\"&TEKST([Rapportage periode];\"YYYY\")&\"(\"&TEKST([Rapportage periode];\"MMMM\")&\")\"</Formula><FieldRefs><FieldRef Name='Rapportage periode' /></FieldRefs></Field>"
, true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldToDefaultView);
```

My question is, What on earth am i doing wrong? I have tested the formula, and it works fine.

Further on, adding the column with the formula:

```
=[Rapportage periode]
```

works, 
adding the formula:

```
=RECHTS("00"&MAAND([Rapportage periode]);2)&"-"&TEKST([Rapportage periode];"YYYY")&" ("&TEKST([Rapportage periode];"MMMM")&")"
```

in the interface works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, after lots of trial and error i got it.

Turns out that

- A, no matter the locale of the site collection, the Client object model must enter in the english syntax.
- B, " and & throw syntax errors unless written as & quot; and & amp; so the correct code is:

  ```
  <Field Type='Calculated' DisplayName='Periode' LCID='1043' ResultType='Text'><Formula>=RIGHT(&quot;00&quot;&amp;MONTH([Rapportage periode]),2)&amp;&quot;-&quot;&amp;TEXT([Rapportage periode],&quot;YYYY&quot;)&amp;&quot; (&quot;&amp;TEXT([Rapportage periode],&quot;MMMM&quot;)&amp;&quot;)&quot;</Formula><FieldRefs><FieldRef Name='Rapportage periode'/></FieldRefs></Field>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you create that throught the UI? I'm not sure about the formula.. but I guess you are missing the space conversion *x0020*

So it encodes like this: 
Rapportage_x0020_periode